# What is the proper way of inserting a pipe into a Java Pattern expression?

Tags: java, regex

What is the proper way of inserting a pipe into a Java Pattern expression?

I actually want to use a pipe as a delimiter and not the or operator.

I.E:

```
"hello|world".split("|"); --> {"hello", "world"}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

in Java 1.5+:

```
"hello|world".split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Answer (score 56):

Escape it with *\\*:

```
"hello|world".split("\\|");
```

Comment: \\ also helped in replacing | with String.repacelAll()

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem a lot (encoding a regex into a Java `String`), so I have bookmarked the [regex tool at fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm); it has a nifty function where it will show you the Java `String` representation of a regex after you test it.

Comment: That's pretty cool!
You could also simply play around with watch statements in the eclipse debug environment.

Answer (score -4):

```
"hello|world".split("\\\\|"); --> {"hello", "world"}
```

First set of `"\\"` only yields the \ as the delimiter. Therefore 2 sets are needed to escape the pipe.

Comment: right solution, wrong explanation. The regexp needed is \| (two characters) and if you want to put a backslash in the string in Java, you need to use a double backslash to tell Java the backslash isn't being used to escape the next character.

Comment: Works fine for me with two slashes. Four slashes splits on every letter, not every word.

Comment: No, it is not doing what you claim; counterexample: https://ideone.com/YC88w0. In regex ``\`` is special character able to create things like `\d` to represent digit `\s` for whitespaces and so son. Also ``\`` is special in String literals which allows us to create line separators `\r` `\n`, tab `\t` and few other things. In regex ``\`` is also used to escape special characters to make them literals like `\+` `\*`. So to escape `|` in regex we need ``\|`` but to create string representing such text we need to write it as `"\\|"`.