# Splitting a string into words in Java

Tags: java

Could you please assist me with the code for splitting this string. I am using **"|"** as a special character to mark how the splitting is to be done

The string is "**The|value|is|infinite**" so that after splitting I have 'the','value','is' and 'infinite' as separate strings. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for the `String` class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cutting / splitting strings with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096660/cutting-splitting-strings-with-java)

Comment: A simple google search or even a search on stackoverflow would yield a number of results. Please search before asking.

Comment: I think the question relates to using a pipe in a regex rather than how the split function works

Comment: Oh, I see. You'll need to escape the vertical bar in your split pattern, i.e. `"\\|"` not `"|"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) works for you.

```
String str = "The|value|is|infinite";
String[] temp;

String delimiter = "\\|";

temp = str.split(delimiter);

for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
   System.out.println(temp[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The pipe `|` can't be included in a split statement as is, you need to escape it with `\\`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "The|value|is|infinite";
    String[] words = s.split("\\|");
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Reference: [What is the proper way of inserting a pipe into a Java Pattern expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433115/what-is-the-proper-way-of-inserting-a-pipe-into-a-java-pattern-expression)

Answer (score 0):

`split` example describes how Java String is split into multiple Java String.

```
String sentence = "The|value|is|infinite" ;  
String[] words = sentence.split("|");  

for (String word : words)  
{  
   System.out.println(word);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "The|value|is|infinite";
for(String s : str.split("|"))
System.out.println(s);
```

You could also use the StringTokenizer class ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html )

Comment: This will split all the lettes

Answer (score 0):

Stringtokenizer class of util package can also help you as below

```
String str = "The|value|is|infinite";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"|");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the vertical bar in your split pattern

```
    String str = "The|value|is|infinite";
    for (String s : str.split("\\|"))
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

```
String input = "The|value|is|infinite";
Scanner output = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\|");
while(output.hasNext()){
     System.out.println(output.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the below code if you like:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SplitString {

```
public static List<String> split(String string, String delimiter) {
    List<String> stringFragments = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String fragments : string.split(delimiter)) {
        stringFragments.add(fragments);
    }
    return stringFragments;
}

public static void printFragments(List<String> stringFragments) {
    for(String fragments : stringFragments) {
        System.out.println(fragments);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> stringFragments = new ArrayList<String>();
    String string = "The|value|is|infinite";
    String delimiter = "\\|";
    stringFragments = split(string, delimiter);
    printFragments(stringFragments);
}
```

}