# Java string split giving unexpected result

Tags: java, string, split

I have this string

```
String x = "2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-13.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-22.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-31.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-40.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-49.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-58.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-64.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4";
```

if i'm doing the split like this `String vec2 [] = x.split(",");` the output it will be this

```
2013-04-17T08:00:00.001
41.14806
-9.58972
-13.0
0.0
0.0
-20.0
```

and so on.

If I'm doing the split like this `String vec2[] = x.split("|");` the output is this:

```
2
0
1
3
-
0
4
-
1
7
T
0
8
:
0
0
:
```

and so on.

And I would expect something similar to this:

```
    2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-13.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4
    2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-22.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4
    and so on
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433115/what-is-the-proper-way-of-inserting-a-pipe-into-a-java-pattern-expression

Comment: `String **vec2[]` is invalid identifier in Java !

Comment: @NoobUnChained I think this is because he wanted it to be bolded.

Comment: Exactly, it was bolded, but someone edited to be in code format (and i'm thankful, because it's better to see) but that ** stayed there.

Now it's correct.

Thanks everybody for the answers, helped me a lot! Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape the `|`:

```
String vec2[] = x.split("\\|");
```

That's because the argument to [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is a **regex** not a string.

In regexes, some characters have special meanings. 
The vertical bar `|` represens alternation. So if you want to split according to `|`, you need to write `\\|` which like telling: "*Don't take* `|` *as a special character, take it as the symbol* `|`".

Answer (score 2):

The argument to split is a regular expression and the "|" character has special meaning. Try escaping it `\\|`.

Answer (score 1):

`String.split(String)` splits on a regular expression, not on a character. As you can see in the [summary of Java regular expression constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), the `|` functions as an `or` construct.

If you want to split on the `|` character, you might need to escape it using `\|`. Note that to escape it in a Java `String`, you'll need to escape the backslash as well: `\\|`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the [`split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a *regular expression* as argument. The pipe (`|`) is a special character in regex and must thus be escaped:

```
        String x = "2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-13.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-22.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-31.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-40.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-49.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-58.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-64.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4";
        String[] arr = x.split("\\|");
        for(String str : arr)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Yields:

```
2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-13.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4
2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-22.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4
2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-31.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4
2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-40.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4
2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-49.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4
2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-58.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4
2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-64.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 String vec2[] = x.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 1):

You  need to escape the `|` character, since it is the regex or pattern.

```
String x = "2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-13.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-22.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-31.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-40.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-49.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-58.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4|2013-04-17T08:00:00.001,41.14806,-9.58972,-64.0,0.0,0.0,-20.0,4";
String[] arr = x.split("\\|");
for(String s: arr){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try escaping the character as such

```
x.split("\\|");
```

Comment: You need to add an extra \ since the \ itself must also be escaped.